# How can I edit the styling of the recent list view?

Tags: visualforce, list-view

I have seen a salesforce org that has a custom styling for the recent list view.

[image: Recent List View example]

I would really like to know how this is possible.

*EDIT - I found the answer*
It is done by modifying search layout.

Comment: Could you post the answer as an answer, and mark it as 'accepted'? That really helps people looking for answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it is done by modifying the search layout tab.

Answer (score 0):

Custom CSS can be added for any page or page box the modifies or overrides the standard CSS styling. Examine the code for the page and you should see the additional tags and styling.